# How to delete node or tag from XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have my XSl as

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:cdm="http://www.businessneed.com/cdm"   
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn cdm xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="cdm" />
<xsl:template match="cdm:attributeList">
        <attributeList>     
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cdm:attribute" />  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and My resultant XML  is as

```
<attributeList>
             <attribute id="1680231133">
                   <attributeCode>FirstName</attributeCode>
                   <attributeValue>Vishal</attributeValue>
              </attribute>

            <attribute id="1680231134">
                   <attributeCode>LastName</attributeCode>
                   <attributeValue>Patil</attributeValue>
              </attribute>
            </attributeList>
```

I want to delete the

```
<attribute id="1680231133">
           <attributeCode>FirstName</attributeCode>
           <attributeValue>Vishal</attributeValue>
      </attribute>
```

So my result will be  only

```
 <attributeList>    
    <attribute id="1680231134">
           <attributeCode>LastName</attributeCode>
           <attributeValue>Patil</attributeValue>
      </attribute>
    </attributeList>
```

Already I tried this:-

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>                 
             <xsl:template match="cdm:attributeList/cdm:attribute/attributeCode/Firstname"/>
```

But Failed to work

How can I achieve this using XSL syntax
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the business requirement behind deleting/removing the node from the output. Is it specific to `@id` value or `FirstName` or the `position()` of the `atrribute` node?

Comment: Thanks for reply Aniket. It is specific to the attribute which contains attributeValue & attributeCode, business  requirement is, this gets rendered in xml file from DB so we want to keep in db but not in xml while xml generates.

Comment: Why are you retrieving the `FirstName` from the DB if you want to remove it from XML. Is it possible for you to modify the DB query? Also my earlier question is related to how you want to remove the `<attribute>` element. Do you want to remove all elements with `attributeCode = FirstName` or `attributeValue = Vishal` or `@id = 1680231133`? How many `<attribute>` elements are there in the XML and how many such `<attributeList>` elements are there?

Comment: @ Aniket I tried going with ID but Id is not fixed it is new every time and gets generated on the fly

Comment: I want to remove all such attributes which are having attributeCode =FirstName. There are around 100+ <attribute> elements in the XML There is only one attributelist. Business doesn't permit to handle at java side, strictly they asked to restrict in XML only. We are using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below XSLT.

It uses an `identity transform` template to copy the input as is to the output and then another template to remove all `attribute` elements having `attributeCode = 'FirstName'`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute[attributeCode = 'FirstName']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<attributeList>
    <attribute id="1680231134">
        <attributeCode>LastName</attributeCode>
        <attributeValue>Patil</attributeValue>
    </attribute>
</attributeList>
```

Comment: Hello Aniket, I have edited my question as you suggested, can you please guide how we can solve the namespace issue? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share the XML snippet that contains all the namespaces? From the shared XSL snippet it looks like you have multiple namespaces involved.

Comment: Hello Aniket it worked Please have a look at my answer
Thanks for the suggestion of namespace, yes did the mistake in namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cdm:attributeList/cdm:attribute[cdm:attributeCode = 'FirstName']"/>
```

I forgot to put namespace prefix in front of the variable "attributeCode"